# Smooth scrolling from one page to a specific section in another page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I building a website in which the homepage has a contact form section and the other pages don't have it. Using Jquery, I made sure that when a user click on the contact link in the navbar on the homepage, the page will scroll down to the contact form section. Let's say a user is on the About Us page and clicks on the contact link, I want the website to take the user back to the homepage and scroll down to the contact form section. Is it possible??

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: check this if it helps
 
https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_eff_animate_smoothscroll

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can scroll down to the target easily using the id's and scroll function script below.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  // Add smooth scrolling to all links
  $("a").on('click', function(event) {

    if (this.hash !== "") {
      // Prevent default anchor click behavior
      event.preventDefault();

      var hash = this.hash;

      $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top
      }, 800, function(){

        // Add hash (#) to URL when done scrolling (default click behavior)
        window.location.hash = hash;
      });
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

you can scroll down to the section you need by using **#** and **href** by  using the below syntax

```
<a href="#section_target">Click Me to Smooth Scroll to Section Below</a>
```

If you want to target the section in other page just use the link followed by the target section Id

```
<a href="index.html#section_target">Take to target section in homepage</a>
```

target **URL** along with the **section Id**

Hope this is what you are looking for..

Comment: This doesnt seem to work for me when you want to target another page. Not sure what I'm doing wrong. Is it because I'm targeting another page within an iframe?