# jQuery scroll to section on another page

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a website which uses jQuery to scroll between a few sections (in page1.html). Now, I added another page to the website (page2.html).

I would like the links in the header of page2.html to link back to the corresponding section in page1.html.

In page2.html I wrote:

```
  <li><a href="page1.html#splash">Home</a></li>
```

This links back to `page1.html#splash`. But on page1, the site does not scroll to the respective section.

My JavaScript is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('a[href=\\#]').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('nav').removeClass('visible');
    $('html,body').stop().animate({scrollTop: $('.'+$(this).data('scrollto')).offset().top-65 }, 700, 'easeInOutExpo', function(){});
});
```

**What I already tried:**

I attempted to add the following code, found [elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45364561/smooth-scrolling-from-one-page-to-a-specific-section-in-another-page),  to page1.html:

```
    <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  // Add smooth scrolling to all links
  $("a").on('click', function(event) {

    if (this.hash !== "") {
      // Prevent default anchor click behavior
      event.preventDefault();

      var hash = this.hash;

      $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top
      }, 800, function(){

        // Add hash (#) to URL when done scrolling (default click behavior)
        window.location.hash = hash;
      });
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

But there is no scrolling to the right section and the console put out the following error: `index.html:19 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined`

Frankly, I am stuck at this point due to lack of expertise in this field.

How do I manage that the site actually scrolls to the right section when coming from another page?

Comment: check your jquery version, 
try "jQuery()" instead of $()

Answer (score 2):

Once you have left the page, the JavaScript from the previous page can't control it. So, you'll need to use jQuery to handle it on the new page when it loads. Place this code on page1.html, changing the comment to the scroll command:

```html
$(document).ready(function() {
    if (window.location.href.includes('#splash')) {
        let animationTime = 100;
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $('.splash').offset().top
        }, animationTime);
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi, thanks! What would be a good way to scroll to `<section class="splash">`  in this case?

Answer (score 0):

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
```

gives this type of error when your page doesn't get the `JQuery`